# Using PowerShell to add values on matching string and output to a new file

Tags: powershell

I have a flat file with 3 columns
Date, Page, and Page Count.

Each page has 2 versions of that page. A secure page and a non secure version(nlbwc)

I want to be able to take all the entries in the file **add the page counts
for that specific date**, and output the file with a generic page name

**So for example,
The data below**

2021-12-06 00:00:00,secure/WebPage1,1806

2021-12-13 00:00:00,secure/WebPage1,1563

2021-12-06 00:00:00,nlbwc/WebPage1,938

2021-12-13 00:00:00,nlbwc/WebPage1,894

2021-12-06 00:00:00,secure/WebPage2,1533

2021-12-13 00:00:00,secure/WebPage2,1351

2021-12-06 00:00:00,nlbwc/WebPage2,450

2021-12-13 00:00:00,nlbwc/WebPage2,360

Would Yield

2021-12-06 00:00:00,**WebPage1,2744** (1806+938)

2021-12-13 00:00:00,**WebPage1,2457** (1563+894)

2021-12-06 00:00:00,**WebPage2,2744** (1533+450)

2021-12-13 00:00:00,**WebPage2,2457** (1351+360)

(The 2 separate values for secure and nlbwc added together based on the date)

This output would be dumped into a csv

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Kindest Regards

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data file looks like this:

```
Date,Page,Page Count
2021-12-06 00:00:00,secure/WebPage1,1806
2021-12-13 00:00:00,secure/WebPage1,1563
2021-12-06 00:00:00,nlbwc/WebPage1,938
2021-12-13 00:00:00,nlbwc/WebPage1,894
2021-12-06 00:00:00,secure/WebPage2,1533
2021-12-13 00:00:00,secure/WebPage2,1351
2021-12-06 00:00:00,nlbwc/WebPage2,450
2021-12-13 00:00:00,nlbwc/WebPage2,360
```

For this you need to use `Group-Object` twice and loop through:

```
# if the data does not have headers, provide them with parameter 
#  -Header 'Date','Page','Page Count'
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\data.csv' | Group-Object {($_.Page -split '/')[1]} | ForEach-Object {
    $pageName = $_.Name
    foreach ($pageGroup in ($_.Group | Group-Object Date )) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'Date'       = $pageGroup.Name
            'Page'       = $pageName
            'Page Count' = ($pageGroup.Group | Measure-Object 'Page Count' -Sum).Sum
        }
    }
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save to new csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\totals.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

```
Date                Page     Page Count
----                ----     ----------
2021-12-06 00:00:00 WebPage1       2744
2021-12-13 00:00:00 WebPage1       2457
2021-12-06 00:00:00 WebPage2       1983
2021-12-13 00:00:00 WebPage2       1711
```

<sup>P.S>=. You made an error in the desired output with regards to the total Page Count numbers</sup>

Comment: This is Glorious. Yes I did make an errors. The gods of Copy/Paste caught me! Thank you so kindly. I can see myself using and modifying this for future endeavors!